# Formatting wget spider output to only include successful urls

Tags: shell, awk, sed, scripting, wget

I'm running wget from a bash shell script with something like this:

```
input=$1

#iterate input text file line by line and run following on each line:

wget -a links.log -nv --spider line_n_url
```

the problem is that the output has many 404 errors and even the url's that do exist are formatted like so:

```
2017-10-10 11:35:46 URL: http://someurl.com/somefile.ext 200 OK
```

Is there a way to format the output that wget writes or easy sed to sort it out?

Additional problem is that the .ext is three possible types which makes matching harder..

What I'm after is each existing URL on its own line without timestamp, `URL:`  or `200 OK`

```
http://someurl.com/somefile.ext
http://someurl.com/somefile2.ex2
http://someurl.com/somefile3.exp
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I understand, you're trying to filter only the `200 OK` messages. You should be looking at **awk** here, so you can do something like this in your bash-script:

```
$ wget -a links.log -nv --spider line_n_url 2>&1 | awk '/200 OK/{print $4}'
http://someurl.com/somefile.ext
```

If you want unique urls, you could do:

```
awk '/200 OK/{print $4}' | sort | uniq
```

or:

```
awk '/200 OK/{a[$4]++}END{for (i in a) print i}'
```

Important: you have to redirect stderr to stdout, like this:

```
$ wget -nv --spider http://google.com 2>&1 | awk '/200 OK/{print $4}'
http://www.google.nl/?gfe_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=qgHdWa2MEqTVXsONudgM
```

Comment: You might need to sort them.

Comment: Yes, you might. Let's be gentle. I'll add it to the answer.

Comment: I was thinking uniq might need them sorted on its input. Didn't mean to be obtuse. :)

Comment: No worries. My mistake.

Comment: I've got this to work with `cat output.log | awk '/200 OK/{print $4}'` but I can't get it to work with wget in the script. Both the output.log and outputting to shell still includes all other lines and unneeded characters, even when I use the piping you mentioned.. what am I doing wrong or does wget not like being piped?

Comment: Added the necessary `2>&1` for redirecting stderr to stdout